# Definition of $C^k( \overline{\Omega})$

Tags: derivatives, continuity, partial-derivative

What is the exact definition of $C^k( \overline{\Omega})$ with $\Omega$ open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$? The functions in that space have domanin $\Omega$ or have domain $\overline{\Omega}$? Is there a general definition in manifold?

Comment: The Banach space with norm $\|f\| = \int_\Omega (|f(x)|+\sum_j |\partial_j f(x)|)dx$ has a subspace of continuously differentiable functions on $\Omega$. When $\Omega$ has a complicated shape there is a smaller subspace which is the space of continuously differentiable functions on some open containing $\overline{\Omega}$.

Answer (score 1):

The definition I know is

$$
C^k(\overline{\Omega}) := \{ v\rvert_{\overline{\Omega}} \mid v \in C^k(U) \quad \text{for some open} \quad U \supset \overline{\Omega}  \}.
$$

I don't know about the manifold part.

Comment: For (differentiable) manifolds it works the same way : for every point $p \in \Omega$, add to $\Omega$ a small neighborhood of $p$ ? For the norm it would need fixing some charts around each $p$, or a metric in the tangent spaces

Comment: Thank you, have you some textbook reference? Hence the functions in that space have doamin $\overline{\Omega}$.

Comment: You definition could be used to define $C^k(X)$  for any set $X$, not only for closure of open set like $\overline \Omega$. Am I right?